# how to delete files with a abc in the middle of the name?

Tags: windows

I have to delete files which have abc in it

example: allgood-abc.2021-01-01.log

how to scan the folder with all the files that have 'allgood-abc as starting alphabets

or better yet, have abc in the file name and delete them ? below is not working for me

forfiles /p Z:\batch-test-delete /M abc*.csv  /c "cmd /c del /q @file

Comment: Test with DIR   dir (* star) adb (* star) .log  and see what it lists.

Comment: @John: Did you mean `dir *adb*.log`

Comment: Dir   * before abc and * after     * does not render properly in a comment here.  Yes as you show with formatting. I will need to learn this.

Comment: backtics (`) worked for me (eventually)

Answer (score 1):

As [John](https://superuser.com/users/1079976/john) suggested

Check first with harmless commands

```
> pushd Documents && dir *and*.txt && popd

14/02/2017  19:48               219 randomwords.txt
22/03/2023  22:17                 7 sandybeach.txt
```

then (carefully) execute the pattern using the dangerous commands

```
> forfiles /P .\Documents /M *and*.txt /C "cmd /c echo @file"

"randomwords.txt"
"sandybeach.txt"
```

<sub>Community Wiki because mostly not own work</sub>